# Any recommendations for low light house plants?

Tags: houseplants, plant-recommendations

I'm looking for a low light plant to have in my bathroom, and looking for recommendations.

I do have one window in the bathroom, but it is has that foggy/blurred treatment on it.

Any insights, advice or recommendations greatly appreciated!

Comment: My dad had a rubber tree in his dark office my whole childhood.

Answer (score 1):

For low-light plants in bathrooms, I recommend growing a golden pothos. We have one in a low-light bathroom (it has a tiny high window, and that's it; it's not by the window; it's about as far from the window as it can get, actually), and it's doing fine. They handle low-light well, and they also handle cool indoor temperatures in unheated rooms well (should that be a concern).

However, make sure you don't over/under-water it, and that you take good care of it (don't neglect it just because it's in the bathroom). Feel the soil to see if it needs more water.

Potassium can be helpful for plants in low light. You might consider giving it a good dose of monopotassium phosphate, or potassium sulfate (note that the phosphate in monopotassium phosphate can make some plants, such as vegetable seedlings, leggier on low light, but it doesn't do that with golden pothos plants, in my experience). The potassium should strengthen the roots a lot, to help protect it against fungi (which would be a bigger concern in a low-light bathroom). Too much nitrogen can have the opposite effect, but they still appreciate nitrogen fertilizers, given appropriately (even in low light).

Thanksgiving cactuses might be another consideration, but they'd probably grow pretty slowly in such conditions (and the roots aren't as vigorous as golden pothos roots).

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations!  I will definitely check both the golden pothos and Thanksgiving cactuses out.  Great tip on the Potassium use too!

Answer (score 0):

Sanseverias ,Janet Craig’s ,cast iron plant ,parlor  palm just to name a few. Make sure to starve your plants in low light because overwatering kills them

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).